# Can't see principle volume with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

I'm working on some tutorials for fog in my scene, I tried to make that fog with those nods but it's not working on Cycles. When I turn on Eevee I can see fog definitely but When it's Cycles,doesn't work. I want to make fogs in my scene. composition also is not working..
How can I make fog in Cycles?

Comment: Are you using the Cycles X branch by chance?

Comment: No, I just use Cycles.

Comment: Could you expand on "composition also is not working.."?

Comment: Yes I tried to add mist to make fog in the scene but , it's not working in Cycles. I don't understand that.

Comment: But I want to make a more formative fog. like a cloud

Comment: Not all of the nodes set up appears in the screenshot provided. Also, the set up is so complicated that a small error anywhere could easily cause “density” to always result in zero. I recommend you try simpler set ups until you isolate the problem.